# Голос против после удаления вопроса?

Tags: дефект, поддержка

При удалении [этого ответа](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522419/178988) видел рейтинг -3, после удаления, причём, лишь обновив страницу после этого, увидел -4. Подумал, что удаление было чуть позже голоса и данные на странице не успели обновиться.

Но потом на странице репутации заметил интересную деталь: строка с -8 по голосам находится выше строки с +8 за удаление ответа. Но ведь выше означает позже. Как так??

[image]

PS: И вообще, не понимаю, почему этот ответ считается хуже принятого.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Время событий на Stack Exchange хранится с точностью до секунды. Если   два действия произошли в течение одной секунды, то информации о том, что из них было раньше, в системе не имеется. Поэтому порядок на странице репутации этого показать не может: события там отсортированы по времени, а если времена совпадают, сервер их вернёт в каком-то порядке, необязательно хронологическом.

Поскольку голосовать по удалённым ответам невозможно, голос был подан до  удаления.

Comment: Эх.. Ну то ж округляет время до секунд??