# Можно дать два голоса за одно сообщение?

Tags: дефект, репутация

Кто-то действительно может дать два голоса сразу?

[image: скрин1]

Если подвести мышью, то всплывает (не знаю как соскринить):

```
"ответ получил голос <<за>> 2 раза"
```

Сначало подумал, что возможно голоса группируются. Но почему я не могу их развернуть?

Для сравнения в моём профиле:

[image: скрин2]

PS Исходя из полученных ответов и комментариев:

- Дать два голоса сразу на одно сообщение не может никто.
- При просмотре чужих профилей, несколько событий по сообшению за день на вкладке репутация отображаютса как одно событие. То есть вместо, например, "2 события" и стрелочка "развернуть", пишет - "голос за" без стрелочки.
- Ошибка проявляется в обычном окне или вкладке Chrome на всех устройствах (пока) только у меня. В приватном окне Chrome и с другими браузерами всё работает как ожидалось.

Comment: Нет, никто не может. Это либо совпадение, либо чья-то хитрая... жилка.

Comment: @D-side Совпадения это хорошо, но когда два раза подряд - это удача.

Comment: Минусы, бывает, прилетают пачками по два, один из которых от [Духа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/%D0%94%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), по наводке некоторыми видами тревог. Но плюсы в основном стихийные.

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, какого числа и у какого участника вы видели соответствующую запись. Я постараюсь разобраться.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10499/777julia777?tab=reputation) 21 и 22 января.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно на информацию со второго снимка посмотреть?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Второй снимок с моего профиля, тогоже дня, таже тема. Я успел посмотреть ваш ответ со скрином. Так у меня для чужих событий нет треугольничка перед названием темы, т.е. я не могу развернуть событие и вижу только сумму с последним временем, а мои события показываются всегда развёрнутыми. Может это и есть ответ?

Comment: @0xdb, ты должен видеть стрелку в чужих профилях. Она даже в приватном окне в незалогиненном состоянии показывается.

Comment: @Qwertiy Рад бы да не вижу. Скрин поправил, там видно, что треугольничка нет. Может Хрома виновата?

Comment: @Qwertiy Точно, дело было в бабине ... С Edge работает.

Comment: @0xdb, попробуй Ctrl+F5, а потом в приватном окне. Возможно дело в каких-то расширениях. Вот скриншот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lrE3.png Кстати, скриншот из хрома.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, в приватном тоже работает. Теперь буду расшиерения отключать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Все расширения отключил, Хрому перестартовал. Всё тоже самое, не работает.

Comment: @0xdb, ерунда какая-то... Должно же работать...

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну да, баг толи в хроме, толи на сайте. Вместо "2 события" и треугольник, пишет "голос за" на тёмно-сером фоне, т.е. не распознаёт два события. Но почему только у меня? Главное вопрос отвечен и ошибка не существенная.

Answer (score 4):

[Ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773543/178988) дан в 08:38:41, а плюсы на него поставлены в 08:39:13 и 08:39:58. Просто после ответа сообщение поднялось на верх главной страницы, где его увидели два пользователя, которые и проголосовали.

Поставить 2 плюса на одно сообщение никто не может.

Comment: Да, это в моём случае, 2 по 10, как и ожидалось. А на верхнем скрине, там 2 голоса в одну секунду?

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, верхний скрин не с моего профиля.

Comment: Не знаю, откуда и что там. Вероятно, совпадение: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3058/178988

Answer (score 4):

Пожалуйста, посмотрите на мой снимок экрана:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть светло и темно серые строки. Светло–серые дают общую сводку за день, темно–серые — информация по каждому из пунктов. Возможно вы где–то развернули информацию и цветопередача вашего монитора не показала разницы?

Comment: По стрелочке куда заметнее, чем по цвету.

Comment: Оказалось баг с Chroma, подробности в коментариях под вопросом.